# how to add onclick event for dynamycally created html table using string format in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating HTML table using table string format, how can I add OnClick event for table row created using JavaScript.

```
HTML += "<tr id=\""+key+"_row\" onclick="showUserInfo('key')"><td class=\"tabletd\"><div id=\""+key+"_author\">" + annotatedBy + "</div ></td><td class=\"tabletd\"><div id=\""+key+"_time\">"+ created_time +"</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what it is that you are having trouble with, but I do see a syntax error that would keep your current code from working as you appear to want it to . . . the following part of the code:

```
. . . onclick="showUserInfo('key')">< . . .
```

. . . would need to be:

```
. . . onclick=\"showUserInfo('" + key + "')\">< . . .
```

. . . in order to insert the value of the `key` variable as the parameter in `showUserInfo`.